# Wp menu links don't work

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, menu

I have created file archive-restaurants.php I tried to load it by pressing menu link. It didnt work. I entered link manually it did work see picture with black area. Then i refreshed it and unfortunately main index page loaded. See seckond picture. How to make this link work?

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tblQN.jpg)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z21nC.jpg)

Comment: can you post the wp_menu code? and check in console if there is any error?

Comment: <nav id="main-nav">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                     'name'=>'Menu Główne'
      ));
     ?>                    
                </nav>

Comment: There's no revelant errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

## Override Wordpress Archive Templates

**Category Archive**

To override an archive with category *restaurants*, then you need to create a file named `category-restaurants.php` in your theme or child theme's folder

You can load that file with this relative link: `category/restaurants/` or this absolute link: `http://example.domain.com/category/restaurants`

**Tag Archive**

You can do the same with tags. Only substitute *category* with *tag*.

`tag-best-restaurant.php` for a *best restaurant* tag

Comment: I've changed file name to category-restaurants.php and entered relative link as you suggested but still I get index page after loading. Do you have any more ideas?Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide a link for inspection. it's hard to tell what's happening. Is it a redirect or some other problem you are overlooking!

Comment: Sorry I work on local disk. I don't have hosting to put it up. Perhaps you have any questions that I could answer?

Comment: I just went through your pics and realized your wordpress install is not rooted to the domain. Remove the beginning slash /category/ -> category/

Comment: No not at all. It should be category/restaurants/ when used in menu link. If you want to test it directly it is localhost:8888/wordpress/category/restaurants/

Comment: Hi Scriptonomy I've tried localhost:8888/wordpress/category/restaurants/ and it loads index page again. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Switch to TwentyFifteen theme and run your override there for a start. Test the override manually also would be helpful. At least you know it is working.

Comment: Thank you Scriptonomy! I've chhanged to TwentyFifteen,tried blog link and switched back to my theme afterwards. Then I entered this link|: http://localhost:8888/restaurants/ and it works!

Comment: Hello @Scriptonomy could I ask your contact details? I have an enquiry